# I take a picture on iOS, do you know how to reduce the size of an FilResult to convert in base64

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, camera, base64

I've created an application iOS in Xamarin I try to take a picture and use it as profile's picture, it works fine but I need to send it to my database and the base64 is way too long. I would like to resize my FileResult to have less characters. Here's my code:

```
 async Task CapturePhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

            if (result != null)
            {
                Stream stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

                using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memory);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    profil.Photo = base64;
                    ImageProfil.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(profil.Photo)));
                    Console.WriteLine(base64.Length);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Erreur", e.Message, "ok");
        }

    }
```

I don't know what the best options is, witch parameters resize first, I've already tried MagickImage but I couldn't make it work and plenty solutions in internet but I'm not sure if I use them right, let me know if you have idea.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/XamFormsImageResize

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works fine but it rotates my picture automatically, I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the *base64.Length*, you could resize the image. Jason has added a good link. I would like to add more details and share a complete solution.

I made a demo using [Xamarin Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to invoke ios native code.

### 1.Create an interface

Create a interface named **IResizeImageInterface** in shared project. And define the method.

```
public interface IResizeImageInterface
{
    byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] imageData,float width,float height,float quality);
}
```

### 2.Implement the interface on iOS

This **ResizeImageService** class is created in iOS project. Invoking this method, we can resize the image as well as reducing the quality depending on the parameter we pass.

```
public class ResizeImageService : IResizeImageInterface
{
    public ResizeImageService()
    {
    }

    public byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] imageData, float width,float height,float quality)
    {


        UIImage originalImage = ImageFromByteArray(imageData);
        UIImageOrientation orientation = originalImage.Orientation;

        //create a 24bit RGB image
        using (CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero,
                                             (int)width, (int)height, 8,
                                             4 * (int)width, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(),
                                             CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
        {

            RectangleF imageRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);

            // draw the image
            context.DrawImage(imageRect, originalImage.CGImage);

            UIKit.UIImage resizedImage = UIKit.UIImage.FromImage(context.ToImage(), 0, orientation);

            // save the image as a jpeg
            return resizedImage.AsJPEG(quality).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static UIKit.UIImage ImageFromByteArray(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        UIKit.UIImage image;
        try
        {
            image = new UIKit.UIImage(Foundation.NSData.FromArray(data));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Image load failed: " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

### 3.Register the platform implementations

This step is easy. Add this line in the **ResizeImageService** class.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyProjectName.iOS.ResizeImageService))]
namespace MyProjectName.iOS
```

Now you can invoke the iOS native code in shared project.

```
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Before resize
    stream.CopyTo(memory);
    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(base64.Length);

    //After resize
    IResizeImageInterface service = DependencyService.Get<IResizeImageInterface>();
    byte[] resizedImage = service.ResizeImage(bytes,400f,400f,0.2f);
    string resizedBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(resizedImage);    
    Console.WriteLine(resizedBase64.Length);
```

And you may see the length reduction after resizing the image.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm facing two problems with this code, first, 'ReduceSize77439838' is not found and second one is that imageRect is a RectangleF and DrawImage need a CGRect. Should I covert imageRect in CGRect ? And do you have a solution for 'ReduceSize77439838' ?

Comment: Oh, 'ReduceSize77439838' is my project name. You should change it to yours. And I think you don't have to convert. I have made some changes to my answer.

Comment: Thanks it's working now, but I have the same problem of rotation than with the Jason's answer, how could I rotate it to have it in a good position in my base64.

Comment: Oh, I am afraid that's a known issue on GitHub : [MediaPicker CapturePhotoAsync - Orientation of photo rotated 90 degrees](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514).